# IP de Telmex para acceder al panel

Tags: ip

Alguien me podría decir cuál es el IP de Telmex para acceder al cPanel y modificar algunas cosas
El IP 192.168.1.254 no accede me dice la conexión no es privada
Nosé si me podrían ayudar

Comment: cPanel es para hosting, ¿Como qué "cosas" quieres modificar?

Comment: No sería mejor ir a soporte de Telmex? No sé, es una idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con

```
ipconfig /all
```

en la linea de comandos ahi te va a decir la direccion de la puerta de enlace,

ahora que si te sale un mensaje  de que la conexion no es privada, en ese mismo mensaje te debe de dar la opcion de continuar, generalmente dice Avanzado, o Opciones Avanzadas